# How to get exactly element in array?

Tags: java, calendar

I have an array:

```
int num[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
```

I get current minute from Calendar and compare it with array above to get exactly element in array.

My code as following, after compare it often get first element, it's not correct as my wish, pls help to correct me. Thanks

```
public static int getMinute(int no) {
    int num[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length;; i++) {
        if (no >= num[i]) {
            no = num[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return no;
}
```

Comment: Why not using `(no / 10) * 10`?

Comment: Looks like you want to round up every minute to the nearest 10th, right? However, it does not look like you are handling numbers higher than 50, ie 56. How should these numbers be treated? Supposedly 0, right?

Comment: my purpose is that, if I get minute XX from system. For example: XX = 10 || 20 || 30 || 40 || 50, I will compare it, if equal I will get value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions (both working in the `0..59` range):

1. If your array is really `0, 10, 20, ..., 50` you could just do:

   ```
   return 10 * (no / 10);
   ```
2. If you have more a more complex matching you could use a `TreeSet` like this:

   ```
   TreeSet<Integer> c = new TreeSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 4, 23, 12, 41));

   System.out.println(c.lower(5));   // return 4
   System.out.println(c.lower(54));  // return 41
   System.out.println(c.lower(32));  // return 23
   ```

   *Just note that you would need to include a lower bound to get it to work, otherwise `TreeSet.lower` might return `null`.*

Answer (score 3):

You would have to change the order of your array for this approach to work. Try

```
public static int getMinute(int no) {
    int num[] = {50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0};
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        if (no >= num[i]) {
            no = num[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return no;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a superfluous semicolon in this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.length;; i++) {
```

Removing it should fix the problem.

Comment: No that would have caused a compilation error. He is getting a result?

Comment: The superfluous semicolon was apparantly only part of the problem here.